# Cassandra counter type in User defined type

Tags: database, scala, playframework, cassandra, user-defined-types

I have a type and a table

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS info(
     street text,
     c_counter counter
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_info info
  );
```

which's way to use the counter on customer table within the UDT?
I tried with this

`UPDATE customer SET customer_info.c_counter = customer_info.c_counter + 1 WHERE id = 6ab09bec-e68e-48d9-a5f8-97e6fb4c9b47;`

and I got the error:
**`SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line xxx no viable alternative at input '+' (...customer SET customer_info.c_counter = [customer_info].c_counter...)">`**

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: what version of cassandra are you running?

Comment: I'm running on version 3.4.2 and 3.7

Comment: Please help me about this problem